# Honeycomb structure shape.

Tags: symmetry, polygons, plane-geometry

A honeycomb structure has hexagonal spaces and walls of some thickness. For a 2-dimensional surface, how can one determine what other shapes are possible(if any) and how would they be oriented to construct a symmetric(2-planes) mesh-like structure?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Are you asking about regular surface tessellations (_q.v._, such as Platonic polyhedral decompositions of the surface of a sphere) that might exist on an arbitrary surface? If so, it might help to add to your question something about your background, and why you're asking (idle curiosity, it's a class project question, you want to program a CNC mill to make some, etc.).

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on some CAD application. While trying to design a mesh-like structure, it occurred to me, if other shapes for the perforations are possible. I could then try to study the strength and shear properties, the material needed per unit area and other things. I do not have much knowledge in advanced higher mathematics, but this problem that I've presented simply applies to one plane.

Comment: Have a look at (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group_diagrams)

Comment: More information about the 17 ways to "pave" the plane in a regular or semi-regular way can be found at (https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/UGpages/Wallpaper.html)

Comment: The suggested links contain info about symmetric patterns but still these examples are not directly useful in my case, as I expect to be able to use such patterns, which are 3D printable.

Comment: Remark: I wasn't informed of your answer because you hadn't mentionned  the addressee (arrobas followed by pseudo). I don't understand very well what you are looking for : something similar to a honeycomb structure, with good resistance that you can 3D print ?

Comment: Yes. In my requirement case, I need a patterned body to create a mesh. I understand symmetric figures are great when it comes to shear and strength properties. Thus I'm looking for some pattern to create for the mesh. I guess, hexagonal honeycomb is great. Otherwise square and triangular shapes too could be used. I wanted to find out what other shapes could be used, or what combination of some shapes would make the strongest pattern.

Comment: I'm going to stick with the hexagon structure. Although here's some nice link I stumbled upon, that deals with hexagons: [link](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

Comment: On the same site, [link](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/grids/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any tiling of the (Euclidean) plane can be used to create a 3D sandwich simply by making each tile the cross-section of a prism and giving all the faces a finite thickness.

The regular hexagonal-prism "honeycomb" which you mention gives the greatest strength for the least material.

If you are interested in other more decorative tilings, the 17 wallpaper groups (mentioned in various comments) describe their possible symmetries. There is an infinite variety of specific tilings with these symmetries, from which honeycomb sandwiches can be derived. See for example the [uniform tilings of the Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tiling), some of which have tiles of several different shapes. Or, hunt around for something that appeals to you, such as the [Cairo tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_pentagonal_tiling). If you feel ambitious, you could even go for an aperiodic tiling such as the [Penrose tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling)

More sophisticated sandwiches with walls which lean sideways are also possible, such as the [spaceframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_frame) structure of alternating octahedral and tetrahedral cells.